# Difference in Storages Spaces feature between Windows 2012 Server & Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, home-server, software-raid, windows-server-2012, storage-spaces

So here it goes,

I have a test bed setup, a machine with three harddrives besides the OS drive and installed on this machine is Windows 2012 Server Standard. 
I have the following Storage Spaces setup
-Thin provivsioning 
-Partity
-3x1TB disks

Now I have a dilmma of sorts, If I want to add another disk to the pool it actully isn't added because it requires me to add 3 disks in addition to the already 3 disks in the pool. This is a bit much for a home setup where I just want to be able to add a disk and extend the storage a bit by bit when needed, not to have to go out and buy a bunch of new hard drives.

Most of the information on the internet regarding Storage Spaces is on Windows 8 Pro. The W8 setup has a completely different GUI and on these websites they seem to hint that you can add a single drive to the setup and Storage Spaces magically adjusts and gives a little more room. So for instance I could add a 2TB drive to the setup and expand the storage without needing to buy 3x2TB disks.

Now my question to community is, is the Windows 8 and Windows 2012 implementation of Storage Spaces different in the regard to being able to add drives?
And if not, how can I accomplish this?